# How to access files inside laravel public folder using Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, assets

I have a project setup that runs Nuxt JS on frontend and Laravel on backend. My project directory setup is something like this

- My App

  - Frontend (Vue)
  - Api (Laravel)

I have made a upload functionality of image which saves the image inside laravel public folder. And my api gives me the the directory of the files stored inside public folder of laravel. Now I want to access the Public folder of laravel from my vue component to display those image.

```
<img :src="`/api/public/${filePath}`" />
```

I tried doing something like this but it redirects to my frontend URL `localhost:3000/api/public/myimage.png`

But I want to access the files inside the public directory of api which runs on `localhost:8080` How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can store images and files in laravel storage and get it by call
backendhost/storage/path
the img tag will be `<img src="backendhost/storage/path" >`
more about laravel storage on link bellow
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#introduction